# Axon - MessageHandlerInterceptor / handler after invocations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, axon

According with documentation: "A MessageHandlerInterceptor can add customized behavior to message handler invocations, both before and after the invocation".

Only before handler invocation is working (handle method).

How can I use it to intercept a call @EventHandler ***after method invocation*** on my event processor class (@ProcessingGroup)?

I'm using Axon 4.3.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When implementing a `MessageHandlerInterceptor`, you are required to implement the following method:

```java
Object handle(
    UnitOfWork<? extends T> unitOfWork, 
    InterceptorChain interceptorChain
) throws Exception;
```

Key when it comes to invoking operations before and after message handling, is *when* you interact with the `InterceptorChain`.
The `InterceptorChain` represent the chain of `MessageHandlerInterceptor` instances in this case. Thus, calling `interceptorChain.proceed()` will tell the chain to move to the following interceptor. If the end of the chain is reached, Axon will move over to the message handling function you have written yourself.

Thus, performing work *after* the `interceptorChain.proceed()` means you are performing work after the annotated method invocation.

You can see how Axon does this itself in the `LoggingInterceptor`, which you can find [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/messaging/src/main/java/org/axonframework/messaging/interceptors/LoggingInterceptor.java).

Comment: Thank you Steven.

Comment: Glad I could help Marcelo. :-)